# How to swap textfield and its label in Drupal

Tags: drupal

I'm using `drupal_render()` to render forms. By default, it renders a label and then a textfield. How can I change this so that the textfield is shown first?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/ may be a more fitting place to post your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Drupal 6**:
You could implement [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) and assign a custom function to the **#theme** attribute of whatever element you want to modify. Then when Drupal wants to render that element, it will call your function, instead of theme_form_element().

Or you could override the [theme_form_element()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/theme_form_element/6) function by copying it to your **template.php** and **renaming it** to *mytheme*_form_element(). Then you can totally modify the way form elements are rendered. Note that **all** form elements are rendered through it, so you're gonna want to check for $element['#name'] so that you only override the output for just the specific elements you need (and this is why doing a hook_form_alter() is a "cleaner" way to do this).

And don't forget to clean the cache whenever your theming modifications don't seem to do anything! :>

Answer (score 1):

Typically you'd handle that kind of overriding at the theme layer. To find out what function or file is generating the output in question, you can use the [Theme Developer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module. Then [override as needed](http://drupal.org/node/173880).

Comment: I'm using something like `<?php print drupal_render($form['SOME_FORM_TEXTFIELD_ELEMENT']); ?>` in my template. But this renders textfields the same way - label after textfield...

Answer (score 1):

You can override field.tpl.php in Drupal 7 and change the position of $label where you want.